# Error: Could not find or load main class when trying to run jar file

Tags: java, jar, compilation, executable, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to create a JAR file of my Java code. There are four classes - `A.java`, `B.java`, `C.java`, and `D.java`. `A.java` has the main method. These are in a folder called `src`, and my manifest file is outside of `src`, and all of my `.class` files are in `bin` which is inside `src`. I created a `MANIFEST.MF` with the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: src/A
```

I then use the command `jar cmf MANIFEST.MF A.jar src/bin/*.class src/GraphFile.txt src/ProblemA.txt src/ProblemB.txt` (there are a few text files I need to include as well in my JAR file). Then, when I run `java -jar A.jar ProblemA.txt GraphFile.txt` (note that `ProblemA.txt` and `GraphFile.txt` are input files that my program accepts and uses), I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.A
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.A
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong or any steps I am missing? Unfortunately, I cannot post the actual code because this is for a class project, but I just need to get it compiled into a JAR file for submission! Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the package for your A class? Is it src?

Comment: You should write fully qualfied class name including package name such as 'com.stackoverflow.A'.